# How to pass a json object to the rest of my project from a web api in javascript

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am making a react web based planer that stores events entered by the user in a sql server accessed by a c# asp.net api. The api and the fetch statement both return what I expect them to, but I'm struggling to pass the data I receive around the rest of my project.

Here is the fetch command I use, with json being the final value I'm trying to use (it holds the details of events in the format Day, Month, Year, Title, Tag)

```
fetch(BaseUrl + '/api/eventreader/6', {
        method: 'GET',
        headers: {
            'Accept': 'application/json',
        },
    })
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(json => {

            
        }

        )
```

I've tried to set a global variable in the file the set it equal to json, but it always comes out as undefined. I have also tried to add the elements to an array, but the array also says it is empty. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a state variable to store the data. For example:

```
const [data, setData] = useState(null);

useEffect(() => {
  fetch(BaseUrl + "/api/eventreader/6", {
    method: "GET",
    headers: {
      Accept: "application/json",
    },
  })
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then((json) => {
      setData(json);
    });
}, []);

console.log(data);
```

Comment: You're welcome. If you have any other questions, please let me know.